# User's name in Ubuntu MATE 16.04 Panel

Tags: 16.04, panel, mate, notification-area

I am new to MATE, and I've noticed some differences from Ubuntu 14.04/GNOME. For example, the Panel. I want to see what I am logged in as. There is no name in the top right corner any more, and in *Users & Groups* I see no option to display it. Can I set it elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to **Control Center > About me**

Or you could begin logging out, and a windows will appear saying

> You are currently logged in as *your name*

Comment: That way I thought of myself. One can also look in Caja and look for the first entry, many ways to find out. But I want to see it, as I change user all the time at this stage of installation